# AngularFireStorage upload multiple image?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am using the Angularfire2 guide to upload images: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md

I have put it into practice and I have managed to upload but only one image per action. Is it possible to load multiple images? How can I achieve it?

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { Observable } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
  <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" />
  <div>{{ uploadPercent | async }}</div>
  <a [href]="downloadURL | async">{{ downloadURL | async }}</a>
`
})

export class AppComponent {

uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
downloadURL: Observable<string>;

constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

uploadFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

  // observe percentage changes
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  // get notified when the download URL is available
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
}
}
```

Comment: Did you work this out ?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, here's how i solved multiple image upload using Angular 8 and Firebase after struggling for days:

```
export class AppComponent {

 uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
 downloadURL: Observable<string>;

 uploads: any[]; // an array that holds the uploaded image URLs and refs

constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

uploadFile(event) {
  this.uploads = [];
  const filelist = event.target.files;

  for (const file of filelist) {
    const path = `product-images/${file.name}`;
    const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
    const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
    //the percentage is still not 100% working as it should
    this.uploadPercent$ = task.percentageChanges();

    // for every upload we will store the image URL in this.uploads array
    const _t = task.then((f) => {
     return f.ref.getDownloadURL().then((imageURLs) => {        
      this.uploads.push(imageURLs);
    })
  });
  }

  
 //we return a promise after making sur all images has been uploaded
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const run = async () => {
   if (this.uploads.length === filelist.length) {
     console.log("All image has been uploaded")
     resolve(this.uploads);
   } else {
     console.log(uploads.length + '/' + filelist.length + ' images has been uploaded..')

    //We check every 500ms if all the image has been uploaded, otherwise we try check again
     return this.delay(500).then(run);
   }
 }
 return this.delay(500).then(run);
 }) 
}


private delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  });
 }
}
```

I know there is an alternative for making async calls using RXJS, but i couldn't make it work. that's why I've implemented deley() function.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be very useful, i will try it

Comment: If that works for you, do not forget to accept my answer !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle uploading multiple files to firebase cloudstorage

1. create a function/service that accepts upload folder/path and array of files to upload
2. let the Function creates a unique filename for each file using [filepath+datetime+index of file] using MD5 hashing or any library you prefer.
3. Create a subject/observable to return the state of the uploads. each file uploaded updates this subject upon completion or error
4. return the subject as observable stream to be subscribed to for results of the multi-uploads

**Define Interfaces**

```
export interface iImageUploadsResult{
file: File;
index: number;
successful: boolean;
downloadUrl?: string;
error?: any
};

export interface iImageUploadsResults{
fileCount: number;
uploadCount: number;
failedCount: number;
completed: boolean;
results: iImageUploadsResult[]
}
```

**Upload Multiple Image function**

```
  uploadMultipleImages(path: string, files: File[], metaData: any){
    const md5 = new Md5();
    const date = new Date().toDateString();

    //Create a stream of upload results for the multiple files. update the stream any time a file is uploads or fails
    const uploadResultsSubject: BehaviorSubject<iImageUploadsResults> = new BehaviorSubject<iImageUploadsResults>({} as iImageUploadsResults);
    uploadResultsSubject.next({completed: false, fileCount: files.length, uploadCount: 0, failedCount:0, results: []}); // Set initial state... isolated for readability


    files.map((file, index) => {
      // Create a unique hash From {Path/datetime/indexOfFile}
     md5.appendStr(path).appendStr(date).appendStr(String(index));
     const filename = md5.end();
     //console.log({filename}) // 1931b9e7b180ab6ace13689d44250712

      const ext = file.type.split('/')[1] //Get file extension
      // Create full file reference from {path/hash.ext}
      const imageRef = ref(this.storage, `${path}/${filename}.${ext}`);

      // Start individual file upload
      const uploadTask = uploadBytes(imageRef, file, {customMetadata: metaData}).then(
        (results) => {
          // Obtain URL of upload file and update resultsStream i.e. [uploadResultsSubject]
          return getDownloadURL(results.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            const uploadState = uploadResultsSubject.value; //current state of subject
            const uploadResult: iImageUploadsResult = {
              file,
              index,
              successful : true,
              downloadUrl: downloadURL
            }

            // Updating subject or stream
            uploadState.results?.push(uploadResult);
            uploadState.uploadCount++;
            uploadState.completed = uploadState.fileCount === uploadState.uploadCount? true : false;
            uploadResultsSubject.next(uploadState);

            return uploadState;
          });
        }
      ).catch(err => { //On error, update subject or stream

        const uploadState = uploadResultsSubject.value;
        const uploadResult: iImageUploadsResult = {
          file,
          index,
          successful: false,
          error: err
        }

        uploadState.results?.push(uploadResult);
        uploadState.uploadCount++;
        uploadState.failedCount++;
        uploadState.completed = uploadState.fileCount === uploadState.uploadCount? true : false;
        uploadResultsSubject.next(uploadState);
      })

    });

    // return Observable of file upload results.
    // When [mageUploadsResults].completed === true. then upload is complete
    // Use  [mageUploadsResults].failedCount for number of failed uploads
    // Use  [mageUploadsResults].results for details of each file upload including downloadUrl
    return uploadResultsSubject.asObservable()

  }
```

You can also add user unique IDs to the MD5 hash to ensure username filename will never be same at any point in time.

**How to call it/Use it**

```
uploadMultipleImages(
    `products/shop/product`, //path or directory
    files, //Files[]
    {shopId: '', productid:''} //Metadata
    ).subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results)
      // {
      //   completed: true,
      //   failedCount: 0,
      //   fileCount: 6,
      //   results: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
      //   uploadCount: 6
      // }

    });
```

You can modify the interfaces and structure as much you want to return any data you wish